# How to import FBX animation to Blender?

Tags: animation, import, keyframes, error, .fbx

Can someone tell me if there is a foolpoof method for importing an animated FBX from 3DS Max to Blender? I have successfully imported several animated FBXs but there a some files which throw errors that I do not understand.

I'm exporting from Max 2017 using the same settings for all (fbx 2017). Upon import I get this error: [image: error]
The rig and skin weight are imported but no animation (no keyframes).  Can someone please help or give me a pointer as to what might be breaking?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have answered my own question - looks like you need to make sure you only import one Mesh object. So if your character uses multiple meshes, you need to combine them. Bad news if you are trying to import multiple meshes with blend shapes/ morph targets!